# How to get enum value by string or int

Tags: c#, enums

How can I get the enum value if I have the enum string or enum int value. eg: If  i have an enum as follows:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3
}
```

and in some string variable I have the value "value1" as follows:

```
string str = "Value1"
```

or in some int variable I have the value 2 like

```
int a = 2;
```

how can I get the instance of enum ? I want a generic method where I can provide the enum and my input string or int value to get the enum instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get enum int value by string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891893/get-enum-int-value-by-string)

Answer (score 387):

No, you don't want a generic method. This is much easier:

```
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)myInt;

MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), myString);
```

I think it will also be faster.

Comment: This is actually the correct way of doing this. There is no generic way to parse types for the same reason why there is no IParsable interface.

Comment: @Johannes What do you mean by that? There is a generic way, refer my answer and others too.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The problem the OP describes is solved like KendallFrey showed it. Generic Parsing can not be done - see here: http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Why-no-IParseable-interface . Any other solution has no advantage compared to the "onboard" solution of C#. The maximum you can have is an ICanSetFromString<T> where you create and initialise an object to its default(T) and in a next step pass in a representative string. This is close to the answer the OP gave - but it is pointless because usually this is a design issue and a larger point in the system design was missed.

Comment: This answer worked very well, especially with the multiple examples of an int and string usage. Thank you.

Comment: I think this works now, it's a bit more concise:

    Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(myString);

Comment: Thank god someone heard my prayers, people are giving way too much complicated answers while askers only look for simple one lined ways to do simple things such as getting an enum value by string.

Comment: One problem with this approach could be (depends on the use case): If myInt has a value that cannot be mapped to an enum value, there is no error and myEnum simply takes the corresponding int value (enum values are ultimately int values).

Answer (score 39):

There are numerous ways to do this, but if you want a simple example, this will do.  It just needs to be enhanced with necessary defensive coding to check for type safety and invalid parsing, etc.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to return an enum value of type T for the given string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value)
    {
        return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to return an enum value of type T for the given int.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this int value)
    {
        var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value);
        return name.ToEnum<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 27):

Could be much simpler if you use `TryParse` or `Parse` and `ToObject` methods.

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static  T GetEnumValue<T>(string str) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(T);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new Exception("T must be an Enumeration type.");
        }
        return Enum.TryParse(str, true, out T val) ? val : default;
    }

    public static T GetEnumValue<T>(int intValue) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(T);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new Exception("T must be an Enumeration type.");
        }
        
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(enumType, intValue);
    }
}
```

As noted by @chrfin in comments, you can make it an extension method very easily just by adding `this` before the parameter type which can be handy.

Comment: Now also add a `this` to the parameter and make `EnumHelper` static and you can use them as extensions too (see my answer, but you have a better/complete code for the rest)...

Comment: @chrfin Good idea, but I don't prefer it as it will be popping in intellisense where it is not required when we have namespaces in scope. It will be annoying I guess.

Comment: @chrfin Thanks for the comment, added as a note in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

As suggested by [@Phil B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6620329/phil-b) in the comments of [@Kendall Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785745/kendall-frey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564167/5604984), this can be done quite concisely for strings.

```cs
Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(myString);
```

Adding this since [@Kendall Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785745/kendall-frey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564167/5604984) gave me a runtime error while [@Phil B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6620329/phil-b)'s revision did not.

Answer (score 9):

Following is the method in C# to get the enum value by string

```
///
/// Method to get enumeration value from string value.
///
///
///

public T GetEnumValue<T>(string str) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new Exception("T must be an Enumeration type.");
    }
    T val = ((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))[0];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        foreach (T enumValue in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            if (enumValue.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(str.ToUpper()))
            {
                val = enumValue;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

Following is the method in C# to get the enum value by int.

```
///
/// Method to get enumeration value from int value.
///
///
///

public T GetEnumValue<T>(int intValue) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new Exception("T must be an Enumeration type.");
    }
    T val = ((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))[0];

    foreach (T enumValue in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(enumValue).Equals(intValue))
        {
            val = enumValue;
            break;
        }             
    }
    return val;
}
```

If I have an enum as follows:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3
}
```

then I can make use of above methods as

```
TestEnum reqValue = GetEnumValue<TestEnum>("Value1");  // Output: Value1
TestEnum reqValue2 = GetEnumValue<TestEnum>(2);        // OutPut: Value2
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Can you also please provide reference of where you got this?

Comment: For this to compile I had to modify the first line to

        public T GetEnumValue<T>(int intValue) where T : struct, IConvertible


Also beware of an extra '}' at the end

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot the generic type definition:

```
public T GetEnumValue<T>(int intValue) where T : struct, IConvertible // <T> added
```

and you can improve it to be most convinient like e.g.:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string enumValue) : where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), enumValue);
}
```

then you can do:

```
TestEnum reqValue = "Value1".ToEnum<TestEnum>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
  public static TestEnum GetMyEnum(this string title)
        {    
            EnumBookType st;
            Enum.TryParse(title, out st);
            return st;          
         }
```

So you can do

```
TestEnum en = "Value1".GetMyEnum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this

It's another way

```
public enum CaseOriginCode
{
    Web = 0,
    Email = 1,
    Telefoon = 2
}

public void setCaseOriginCode(string CaseOriginCode)
{
    int caseOriginCode = (int)(CaseOriginCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(CaseOriginCode), CaseOriginCode);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this moment its possible to use the Enum.TryParse method:

```
MyType myType;
bool isValidEnum = Enum.TryParse(yourStringValue, out myType);
```

If "yourStringValue" is not of MyType enum type then isValidEnum is false.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

From SQL database get enum like:

```
SqlDataReader dr = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) {
   EnumType et = (EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), dr.GetString(0));
   ....         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get string/value

```
    public enum Suit
    {
        Spades = 0x10,
        Hearts = 0x11,
        Clubs = 0x12,
        Diamonds = 0x13
    }

    private void print_suit()
    {
        foreach (var _suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            int suitValue = (byte)(Suit)Enum.Parse(typeof(Suit), _suit.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(_suit.ToString() + " value is 0x" + suitValue.ToString("X2"));
        }
    }
```

---

```
    Result of Message Boxes
    Spade value is 0x10
    Hearts value is 0x11
    Clubs value is 0x12
    Diamonds value is 0x13
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following method to do that:

```
public static Output GetEnumItem<Output, Input>(Input input)
    {
        //Output type checking...
        if (typeof(Output).BaseType != typeof(Enum))
            throw new Exception("Exception message...");

        //Input type checking: string type
        if (typeof(Input) == typeof(string))
            return (Output)Enum.Parse(typeof(Output), (dynamic)input);

        //Input type checking: Integer type
        if (typeof(Input) == typeof(Int16) ||
            typeof(Input) == typeof(Int32) ||
            typeof(Input) == typeof(Int64))

            return (Output)(dynamic)input;

        throw new Exception("Exception message...");
    }
```

**Note:this method only is a sample and you can improve it.**

Answer (score -2):

```
Enum.valueOf(myEnum.class, myString)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here ise better solution

```
public static string AsString<T>(this T value) where T : Enum
{
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value);
}

public static T AsEnum<T>(this int value) where T : Enum
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value))
    {
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{value} is not a valid value for enum {typeof(T).Name}");
    }
}
public static int AsInt<T>(this T value) where T : Enum
{
    return (int)(object)value;
}
```

Comment: Yiğitcan Ölmez, please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: is answer enough