# Get any enum from ComboBox

Tags: c#, types, enums, enumeration

I'm programming in WPF(C#). I populate a `ComboBox` with this function:

```
public static void PopulateComboBox(ComboBox cmb, Type type)
{
    foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(type))
    {
        cmb.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Now I need a method like this (as illustrated below) to get `any enum` as output:

```
public static enum PopulateComboBox(ComboBox cmb, string nameOfEnum, Type type)
{

}
```

How can I write such function?

Comment: do you mean `public static Enum...`? not sure what you're asking, what's your problem?

Comment: you cannot return `enum`. I think what you mean is to return something of type Enum.

Comment: what is the purpose of `List<string> names = new List<string>();`?

Comment: @KernelMode Thank you for your comment. I forgot to remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into adding the enum values to the ComboBox directly instead of their names.

Another option would be `Enum.Parse(Type enumType, string value)`.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found my answer in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563960/how-to-get-enum-value-by-string-or-int). My answer is:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value)
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}
```

For example I call it in this way:

```
BorderType borderType = ToEnum<BorderType>("Constant");
```

where `BorderType` is an `enum` (from OpenCV);